# Error Expected browser binary location when run selenium in windows hosting

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

this sample work:
get text of google and show in home page sample asp.net
test for correct work selenium in windows host.

i want to run selenium in windows hosting plesk.

error for me:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default
>   location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no
>   binary flag set on the command line (SessionNotCreated)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Expected browser
>   binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no
>   'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag
>   set on the command line (SessionNotCreated)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>   Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Expected browser binary location, but
>   unable to find binary in default location, no
>   'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag
>   set on the command line (SessionNotCreated)]
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response
>   errorResponse) +1059
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) +125
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities
>   desiredCapabilities) +235
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor
>   commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) +54
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxOptions options)
>   +81    WebDriverwithwebapp._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +178
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +51    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +678

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.BrowserExecutableLocation = ("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); //This is the location where you have installed Firefox on your machine

       // WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

        using (var FireFoxPage = new FirefoxDriver())
        {
            //_driver = new FireFoxDriver();
            _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            _driver.SwitchTo().Window(_driver.CurrentWindowHandle);
            _driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
            // _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com/");

            _driver.FindElement(By.Id(Button_ID)).Click();


          IwebElement  Element1 = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[3]/span"));
            ksc = Element1.Text.ToString();

            Label1.Text = ksc.ToString();

            _driver.Quit();
            Process[] geckodriverProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("geckodriver");
            foreach (var geckodriver in geckodriverProcesses)
            {
                geckodriver.Kill();
            }

        }



    }
```

Comment: The error indicates that the path to the firefox executable is wrong. Have you checked that it is correct? Is Firefox also installed on the server where you want to execute the code?

Comment: Run to windows hosting plesk.

Comment: no solution?!!!!!  `unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the `options` variable into the parameters of `new FirefoxDriver()`. It worked for me like this:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.BrowserExecutableLocation = ("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); //This is the location where you have installed Firefox on your machine

   // WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

    using (var FireFoxPage = new FirefoxDriver(options))
    {
   //...
```

Actually, I see a commented variable using the `options` object, did you have any errors using it instead?

Answer (score 0):

Find the installed location of firefox
e.g. C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe

```
FirefoxOptions option = new FirefoxOptions();
option.BrowserExecutableLocation = "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";
```

//Location of geckodriver.exe file in project solution
string path = "C://Users//v-sacgupta//source//repos//PracticeExcersice//PracticeExcersice//drivers//";

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(path + @"/drivers/", option);
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).